# iPhone App for monitoring HP NonStop servers

Tags: ios5, hp-nonstop

We are planning to create an iPhone app that will monitor certain entities on the HP's NonStop platform. We already have our custom host web server components running on the NonStop platform handling http(s) requests and sending back XML response (to browser and desktop based applications). 
Being a novice in the iOS space and after reading Apple's stringent app approval guidelines, I would like to know if such a http(s) communication is allowed on the iOS, since the web server being used here is our own and not one of the more known/acceptable ones (e.g. Apache).
In its simplest form, the app will send a URL request to the NonStop host component and in return read and parse the XML that gets returned in the response. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"I would like to know if such a http(s) communication is allowed on the iOS, since the web server being used here is our own and not one of the more known/acceptable ones (e.g. Apache). "

Yes, it is allowed the https to a desired host.
I don't think is  matter for Apple what is on your host.

To optimize the comminication speed/overhead I would use JSON instead of xml

Comment: Thanks for confirming the https communication. Is http also allowed?

Comment: yes, it is allowed http to. (You are not allowed: to use undocumented API/private API from iOS classes)

Comment: I can recommend http://www.inductum.com/atombox/api/ for REST API development on HP NonStop -> NodeJS port on HPNonStop